# Laravel Guzzle Middleware for requests headers

Tags: laravel, http, request, guzzle

I have a controller that sends http requests to external urls via Guzzle.
And there are many such controllers, how to make a middleware that will add a certain header to each request, instead of adding method 123 to the zoo in each controller

My Controller:

```
class PostController extends Controller {
public function getLastRecord() {
    $lastRec = Post::latest('created_at')->first();

    $body = collect([$lastRec])->map(function($record) {
        return [
            'id' => $record->post_id,
            'rec_name' => $record->post_name,
            'user' => $record->user_id,
        ];
    })->toArray();

    $response = Http::withToken('1Asaciry$rsW$')->post('http://post.com', $body);       

    return $response;
}
```

}

And I don't want to use *withToken*, I just want to use ::post, but in each request, the "Authorization" header will be added: "1as City$rsW$".

Comment: A `service provider` would be more appropriate for this task, than middleware.

Comment: need to work it only in guzzle requests

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom class or helper function or controller method to handle this and encapsulate what you need in all guzzle requests

```
function myHttp()
{
return Http::withToken('1Asaciry$rsW$') ;
}
```

Then chain to it rest of request

```
$response= myHttp()->post()
```

Comment: custom class need use in each cobtroller

Comment: You need to use Http class in each controller. Instead of Http class use custom class. Your custom class can extend Http class

Comment: What are you say about this - https://bitpress.io/laravel/php/2017/04/07/laravel-guzzle-6-middleware/ ?

Comment: ....any ideas ?